# How to set drawable icon with text in the center of AppCompatButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-appcompat

As the title, I want to create a `AppCompatButton` with icon and text in the center. I used this method but it's not work:

```
Spannable buttonLabel = new SpannableString(" Button Text");
buttonLabel.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon,      
ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
button.setText(buttonLabel);
```

I also disabled `setTextAllCap` in the `xml` layout but nothing changed. Please help me to solve this solution.

Comment: why not to use `setCompoundDrawables` instead?

Comment: I also try to use setCompoundDrawables but the icon is not centered with text.

Comment: what is your `android:gravity`?

Comment: I set `android:gravity="center"` but the icon still in the left of button

Comment: and how does it look with `setSpan`?

Comment: The `setSpan` not work. the button is empty with exactly above code

Comment: @Glenn why use applicationContext instead of activity context. anyway it works for me

Comment: @Raghunandan Could you send me the full source code that works with you

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/9YQ19pjg) just works, i have no idea why it doesnt at you, most likely you are using the wrong `Context`

Comment: As the question I used `AppCompatButton` and the above code not work.

Comment: so change `Button b = new Button(this);` to `Button b = new AppCompatButton(this);` and the above code does work (just paste it in your Activity#onCreate method and you will see your button with the image and text)

Comment: Sorry, but it's not the solution for this issue

Comment: Please add your layout. Probably your 'button' width is match_parent.  You can wrap it with FrameLayout.

Answer (score 4):

use padding

```xml
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_refresh"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/buttonPadding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/buttonPadding"
            android:text="test" />
```

but you need to handle multiple screen sizes